# Error with string library in c++ :: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string (lldb)

Tags: c++, string, xcode

I am asked to ask for a phrase and a word and replace all the words for " * ".

Example:
Phrase: I love dogs but my sister doesn't like dogs

Word: dogs

Final Phrase: I love * but my sister doesn't like *

When i put a cout of the phrase inside the loop it displays it as it should be but i am getting an "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string
(lldb)" error

You need at least 10 reputation to post images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/00FJl.png

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string frase;
string palabra;
getline(cin,frase);
getline(cin,palabra);
int longitud = palabra.length();
int encontrar = frase.find(palabra);

while(encontrar != 1){
    if(encontrar != 1){
        encontrar = frase.find(palabra);
        frase.erase(encontrar,longitud);
        frase.insert(encontrar, " * ");

    }
    cout<<frase<<endl;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `string::find` in the wrong manner.

[`string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) returns:
- The position of the first character of the first match.
- `string::npos` if no matches were found.

So your check should have a comparison with `string::npos`. You can modify your `while` loop like this:

```
while(encontrar != string::npos){
        frase.erase(encontrar, longitud);
        frase.insert(encontrar, " * ");
        encontrar = frase.find(palabra);
}
```

See [demo here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MXnZvbDVUhwsw3A5).